# Query for username in Salesforce iOS SDK

Tags: ios, salesforce

I have an iOS app using the latest Salesforce iOS SDK.  It authenticates users through a webview using oAuth2.0 on the Salesforce site so I do not capture the username in my app.  Is there a way that I can query for the username either using the API or the session information somehow?  I just want to be able to display the username so that the user knows which account they have logged into (if they have more than one)
Thanks,
Joseph

Comment: Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574257/how-to-get-salesforce-logged-in-user-claims-in-ios-native-application I am also facing same issue and am not getting whether am going in right way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

username of current user is stored in SFIdentityData object

```
#import "SFIdentityData.h"

NSString *userName = [SFAccountManager sharedInstance].idData.username;
```

Comment: great answer, I had been stuck for hours trying to find a way of getting the userid and related data. Many thanks.

Comment: In new versions of the API it is `[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].idCoordinator.idData.username;`

Comment: @NicHubbard I'm using latest version and when I try to log username it gives me null. Can you please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574257/how-to-get-salesforce-logged-in-user-claims-in-ios-native-application Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether you use REST or SOAP API...

For **REST** there's an excellent article by [metadaddy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy): http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_at_Salesforce.com#The_Force.com_Identity_Service

Identity Service link is in format of `/id/(organization id)/(user id)`, scroll up in this blog post a bit to find out when you should expect it.

[image: Workbench]

**SOAP** API, offers [`getUserInfo()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo.htm) method (it returns an object similar to Apex `UserInfo` class). Just click the first link there to see the full list of methods you can call.

Answer (score 1):

**FOR SWIFT**

To display full name and chatter profile picture of logged in user in UILabel and UIImageView using Salesforce Mobile SDK 4 you need to first create @IBOutlets

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourtextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
```

Then all you need is the following in your viewDidLoad()

```
yourtextLabel.text = SFAuthenticationManager.sharedManager().idCoordinator.idData.displayName

let imageURL = SFAuthenticationManager.sharedManager().idCoordinator.idData.pictureUrl
let image =  UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL!)!)
profileImage.image = image
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import **SFAuthenticationManager**.h class

```
#import <SalesforceSDKCore/SFAuthenticationManager.h>
```

then you can get user details (**first name**, **last name**, **email** etc.) this way

```
NSLog(@"userData= %@",[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].idCoordinator.idData);

NSLog(@"first name = %@",[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].idCoordinator.idData.firstName);
NSLog(@"last name = %@",[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].idCoordinator.idData.lastName);
NSLog(@"email name = %@",[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].idCoordinator.idData.email);
```

Answer (score 0):

**SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS 7.0**

**Swift Version**

```
import SalesforceSDKCore
```

```
guard let userId = UserAccountManager.shared.currentUserAccountIdentity?.userId else {return}
```

Depends on what you need, this maybe helpful as well:

```
guard let userId = UserAccountManager.shared.currentUserAccount?.idData?.userId else {return}
```