# Ways to fetched the credentials of the logged in user in Salesforce SDK iOS

Tags: ios, salesforce

Is there a way to get the details/credentials (email, password, name, etc.) of the logged in user using salesforce SDK or even third party libraries?. After allot of googling and searching, i found this link but doesn't work on me:

[Query for username in Salesforce iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447328/query-for-username-in-salesforce-ios-sdk)

Comment: if there is no answer, why it's down vote?

Comment: I would guess the down vote is for saying "it doesn't work for me" without any more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Fetched the email/username and the user iD. I didn't notice the comment below. And yes password cannot be fetched thank you @john. You certainly cannot fetch the user's password nor should you be able to -- that's the entire point of OAuth.

```
#import "SFIdentityData.h"
#import "SFAuthenticationManager.h"

userName = [SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].idCoordinator.idData.username;
NSString *userID = [SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].idCoordinator.idData.userId;

NSLog(@"User name: %@ and User ID: %@", userName, userID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> Is there a way to get the (..) password
```

No.

Comment: how about username, email or name of the user?

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT**

```
YourTextLabel.text = SFAuthenticationManager.sharedManager().idCoordinator.idData.displayName
YourSecondTextLabel.text = SFAuthenticationManager.sharedManager().idCoordinator.idData.email
```

Comment: Right now, it's a code dump. You can add some description to make your post as a good answer.

Comment: haha, ok, well, this answers what the question was seeking in Swift.